Getting ECONNREFUSED error when using Sequelize in GitHub Actions and Docker
I run an integration test using GitHub actions whenever I push to a PR in my repository. This test first creates a MySQL database within a docker image, connects to it (using sequelize), populates it, and runs tests using that database. When GitHub actions runs this test, it fails when sequelize tries to connect to this mysql database and returns an ECONNREFUSED error. When I run the test locally, I have no issues, and this error does not appear. I don't know why this error is happening and why it only happens when running on GitHub actions since it works when running it locally.
I should add that this was all working until two weeks ago. It just "spontaneously" started failing without making any changes to the code.
The exact error is:
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3305
ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3305
...
parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3305
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1605:16) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3305,
    fatal: true
  }

Here is my GitHub actions .yml file:
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    name: "Building"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Use Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v4
      with:
        node-version: 20
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm test // this is the relevant test that is failing

Here is my docker-compose.test.yaml file:
version: "3.3"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./init_db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - 3305:3306
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

And here is the relevant part of my test code:
async function setUpMySQLServer() {

  // Stop any existing MySQL container.
  child_process.spawnSync("docker-compose", ["-f", __dirname + "/docker-compose.test.yaml", "down"]);

  // Start a container for MySQL server.
  const { status, stderr, error } = child_process.spawnSync("docker-compose", ["-f", __dirname + "/docker-compose.test.yaml", "up", "--detach"]);

  if (error)
    throw new Error("Unable to run docker-compose. Docker is required in order to set up a MySQL server.");
  if (status != 0)
    throw new Error("docker-compose exited with an error: " + stderr);

  console.log("Docker set up...");

  await sleep(30000);  // Wait for MySQL server to start (did this as an attempt to fix the issue, does not work)

  // Connect to the MySQL server.
  let sequelize;
  try {
    sequelize = new Sequelize("test", "root", "root", {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 3305,
      dialect: "mysql",
      dialectOptions: {
        decimalNumbers: true,
        multipleStatements: true
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    throw new Error("Unable to connect to the MySQL server. Make sure the MySQL server is running and the connection settings are correct.");
  }

  // Wait for the MySQL server to be up.
  let attempts = 0;
  while (true) {
    attempts++;
    try {
      // Test the connection. This is where I am getting the ECONNREFUSED error.
      await sequelize.authenticate();
      break;
    } catch (error) {
      if (attempts >= 300) {
        console.log(error.message);
        throw error;
      }
    }

    await sleep(1000);
  }

  await populateDatabase(sequelize);
  sequelize.close();
}

I've tried to add more sleep time to give the MySQL database enough time to set up. I have also tried changing the port number, the node version used, adding extra_hosts: - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway" as an option for docker, and adding pooling connection options to sequelize. Since the test passes successfully when doing this on my local machine, I expect it to work when GitHub Actions runs it, but it seems not to work anyways.
One clue that might be related to the issue or not is that I get an "allow access to files" popup when running the test locally for the first time. I accepted and never got it again, but I had someone else run it and not allow it, and they got this same error. I am not familiar enough with GitHub actions to know if this is the cause or how I could fix this.
Any advice is greatly appreaciated! Thank you!

Where does this piece of code run? If within the same container as mysql, then you should use port 3306, not 3305. If outside of the container, then 127.0.0.1 points to whereever your code is run, not ti the container.

It runs within the same container as MySQL. I have tried to switch to port 3306, and it doesn't fix the issue, unfortunately. I don't use port 3306 in case its used by another process, but since I specify that on the docker-compose.test.yaml file it shouldn't be the issue. I could use a random port number and it should be ok. I should add that this was all working until two weeks ago. It just "spontaneously" started failing without making any changes.

Then perhaps the code runs before mysql service is up and running

That's what I thought, but even if I make the program sleep for 15 minutes to wait for it, it still returns that error. Thank you for the advice though.

I fixed the issue by fixing the version of MySQL on the docker-compose.test.yaml file:
version: "3.3"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ...

The issue seems to be that the docker container uses the latest MySQL version, and the latest version is not stable and might have conflicts with docker at the moment. Fixing this version to a stable version allows it to run successfully. There were no problems with the host, ports, or mysql set up time.
